# how do i print only the exception name in java instead of complete name?

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception

how do i print only the exception name in java instead of complete name ?

for e.g IllegalArgumentException exception -

it return exception --

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: some message

but i want to return only this -

> IllegalArgumentException: some message

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Class object you can call `getSimpleName()`.

```
    Class cls = Integer.class;
    System.out.println(cls.getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 0):

For your own custom exceptions you can override `toString()` to format return value.

For exceptions from the standard library and other frameworks you may want to have a method which looks something like this:

```
void formatExceptionMessage(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

You could place this in a class where you have other utility methods and call it whenever you catch an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Some message");
        }catch (Exception exception){
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s",exception.getClass().getSimpleName(),exception.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Some message
```